# DIV dynamically resizing using vertical slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

This is a little hard to explain, but I'm going to do my best:

My webpage is divided using two divs: one floating at left, and other floating at right (50% each one more or less).

I want to add a new feature: **dynamically resize**. That is: when I click on right border of DIV#1 or click on left border of DIV#2, each one should resize from left to right or right to left.

Maybe you don't understand me, but this effect is what I need (from [this plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/)):

[image: JQuery beforeafter plugin]

This plugin only works for images, not divs. I need the same effect on my divs. Actually, I'm trying to use [JQueryUI Resizable class](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) but I don't know how to synchronize both resizes.

Can you help me? Any suggestion or track about this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this functionality using 15 lines of JS/jQ: http://jsfiddle.net/xSJcz/

Hope it helps! You could easily modify it to respons to click, or similar.

EDIT: For future records, here is the answer's CSS:

```
#left,#right{
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:48%;
}
#handle{
    background:#000;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    margin:1px;
    width:1%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
<div id="handle"></div>
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>
```

JS:

```
var h = $('#handle'),
    l = $('#left'),
    r = $('#right'),
    w = $('body').width() - 18;

var isDragging = false;

h.mousedown(function(e){
    isDragging = true;
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    isDragging = false;
}).mousemove(function(e){
    if(isDragging){
        l.css('width', e.pageX);
        r.css('width', w - e.pageX);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need but setting min and max width for each div. How can I modify it to add this personal config?

Comment: Modify the line *if(isDragging){* to check the bounds: *if(isDragging && e.pageX < w*3/4 && e.pageX > w/4){*. You could use constant values instead of course, but I wrote one quarter to the left and two quarters to the right.

Comment: In your demo, the handle jumps to the right (for ~20px) once you start dragging.

Comment: Yes, because of the padding and margin of outside elements (<body>, in this example)