# How to create a re sizable only vertically div? (alike SO form)

Tags: javascript, html, resize, draggable

What we need is simple - 3 divs whose width is static - not changable

- one on top (of page) - resizable ONLY vertically
- one draggable - "separator" in the middle (of page) (not resizable)
- one div just above that "separator". It shall move but not resize while the "separator" is beeng dragged.

we need them to be divs - not text fields because I plan to host in resizable a flash object. jQuery can be used. How to create such thing?

Comment: And what have you tried? What's your mark-up..?

Comment: Btw in Chrome you can resize the text-box horizontally too.

Comment: In the middle of what? On the top of what?

Comment: @Šime Vidas edited, we need it not to be resizable horizontally at all.

Comment: I hope [this past answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180806/div-dynamically-resizing-using-vertical-slide) can help you . I know that this isn't exactly what you need, but probably it can give you a few ideas

Comment: @Fran Verona thanks - forked, done here http://jsfiddle.net/LGPVv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, only tested in Chrome. Hopefully it will get you on your way.

http://jsfiddle.net/tZQx7/2/

Edit: fixed jsfiddle link, was point to an older version